# How to change PlotMarker style for DateListPlot conditionally?

Tags: plotting

Suppose given a `Timeseries` as follows:

```
    timeseries = 
     TimeSeries[{{DateObject[{2019, 10, 11, 9, 30, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
   "GMT"], Quantity[3.31034, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 11, 12, 55, 12.7246}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[8.03562, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 11, 12, 59, 38.6056}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[10.6702, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 11, 19, 38, 7.59068}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[10.7163, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 11, 19, 47, 14.0512}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.5236, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 12, 11, 17, 38.344}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[10.1256, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 12, 11, 24, 25.9655}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[12.473, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 12, 15, 47, 23.4446}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[12.8601, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 12, 15, 57, 29.7299}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.9472, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 12, 16, 15, 27.5256}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.9695, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 13, 11, 57, 49.6882}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[12.5608, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 13, 12, 5, 33.0523}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.0108, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 13, 12, 15, 42.4877}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.4455, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 13, 20, 43, 19.3294}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.6496, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 13, 20, 49, 7.69868}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.9309, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 14, 13, 30, 23.8059}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[13.5239, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 14, 13, 35, 41.3057}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.5704, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 14, 13, 41, 43.7842}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.6127, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 14, 13, 46, 54.216}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.391, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 14, 20, 8, 55.3773}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.3049, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 15, 10, 59, 29.7726}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.5725, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 15, 11, 5, 52.2133}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.4151, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 15, 14, 1, 7.18972}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.8583, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 15, 14, 6, 28.1324}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.4715, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 15, 18, 48, 11.7907}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.6273, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 16, 0, 18, 58.2619}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.2788, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 12, 29, 30.7814}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[12.9294, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 12, 40, 8.33544}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[13.5091, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 12, 47, 24.3058}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.0923, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 14, 43, 44.6881}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[14.5118, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 14, 48, 27.909}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.0909, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 14, 52, 29.968}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.524, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 19, 48, 37.0089}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.4967, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 21, 50, 27.8946}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.8744, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 17, 22, 1, 8.0006}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[16.4192, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 18, 9, 30, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[15.6493, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 25, 9, 30, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[8.28531, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 0, 5, 19.0775}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.40224, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 0, 8, 43.0075}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.50554, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 0, 37, 14.5114}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.60282, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 19, 29, 28.1093}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.5433, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 19, 34, 36.2571}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.7419, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 10, 30, 19, 39, 50.0777}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.9404, 1/("Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 11, 1, 9, 30, 0.},
    "Instant", "Gregorian", "GMT"], 
  Quantity[6.52652, 1/(
   "Days")]}, {DateObject[{2019, 11, 8, 9, 30, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", "GMT"], Quantity[4.99927, 1/("Days")]}}];
```

I want to plot the `TimeSeries` with conditional `PlotMarkers` which are red for values above 10.

Since I can't find the `StylingFunction` I tried to fake it with `LabelingFunction` as follows:

```
DateListPlot[timeSeries, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 LabelingFunction -> (If[Last@#1 > 10, 
     Callout[Style["•", Red], Center]] &)]
```

But the result is very bad. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can post-process the output to change the color of `Inset` objects:

```
postProcess = # /.  GeometricTransformation[Inset[a_, b___], c_] :> 
     MapThread[GeometricTransformation[Inset[Style[a, #2], b], #] &,
     {{Select[#[[1, -1]] >= 10 &][c], Select[#[[1, -1]] < 10 &][c]}, {Red, Blue}}] &;

postProcess @ DateListPlot[timeseries, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, generate a second plot with the option `Joined -> False` and style individual data elements using `PlotStyle` and use `Show` to combine the two plots:

```
Show[DateListPlot[timeseries],
 DateListPlot[List /@ timeseries["Path", 1], Joined -> False, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  PlotStyle -> (If[QuantityMagnitude[#2] >= 10, Red, Blue] & @@@ timeseries["Path", 1])]]
```

[image]

**3.** You can add markers as metadata and use the options `LabelingSize` and `LabelingFunction` to control the size and placement of the markers:

```
markers = If[#[[2, 1]] >= 10, Style[●, Red], Style[●, Blue]] & /@ timeseries["Path", 1]; 

DateListPlot[timeseries -> markers, 
 LabelingSize -> Medium, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#3[[3, 1]], Center] &), 
 GridLines -> {None, {10}}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"more than 10", "less"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> False]]
```

[image]